# Linq-SQL Generic GetById with a custom Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, expression

I've created a generic to target tables in my database. I've also added a generic .where() with an expression containing only 1 parameter in the lambda expression. Is there a way that I can add more than 1 parameter in the same expression? Please ignore the fact that the below method returns 1 item, I would like to make it return a IList.

Here's my method:

```
public virtual T GetById( Int32 id, String someStringColumn )
{
   ParameterExpression itemParameter = Expression.Parameter( typeof( T ), "item" );
   var whereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>
                (
                Expression.Equal( Expression.Property( itemParameter, "Id" ), Expression.Constant( id ) ),
                new[] { itemParameter }
                );

   return context.Set<T>().Where( whereExpression ).FirstOrDefault();
   }
```

My actual intentions for this method is to later perform a Contains() on "string" properties of the target table "T". I would like to do something like below and append to the above Expression a check if the String property contains a value in the "someStringColumn". Just an insight, the "someStringColumn" will be a general search string on my page past by Ajax on every back-end call.

```
var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties().Where( p => p.PropertyType == typeof( string ) ).ToArray();

for ( Int32 i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++ )
{

}
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this in a non-generic method:

```
    public override List<TableInDatabase> List( PagingModel pm, CustomSearchModel csm )
    {
                String[] qs = ( pm.Query ?? "" ).Split( ' ' );

                return context.TableInDatabase
                              .Where( t => ( qs.Any( q => q != "" ) ? qs.Contains( t.ColumnName) : true ) )
                              .OrderBy( String.Format( "{0} {1}", pm.SortBy, pm.Sort ) )
                              .Skip( pm.Skip )
                              .Take( pm.Take )
                              .ToList();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are seeking for something like this:

```
var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
Expression body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(item, "Id"), Expression.Constant(id));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(someStringColumn))
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)).ToList();
    if (properties.Any())
        body = Expression.AndAlso(body,
            properties.Select(p => (Expression)Expression.Call(
                Expression.Property(item, p), "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(someStringColumn))
            ).Aggregate(Expression.OrElse));
}       
var whereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
```

i.e. build `Contains` expression for each string property, combine them using `Or` and finally combine the result with the first condition using `And`.

Comment: Hi Ivan Stoev, thank you for your answer, it looks correct and I will let you know once I've tested your solution. Thanks once again...

Comment: I'm getting error: "Expression expected". This is how the generated expression looks like though:
{item => ((item.Id != 0) AndAlso ((((((((((item.ModifiedBy.Contains("") OrElse item.Number.Contains("")) OrElse item.Branch.Contains("")) OrElse item.DirectorateProject.Contains("")) OrElse item.DepartmentSubproject.Contains("")) OrElse item.OtherSupplier.Contains("")) OrElse item.OtherSupplierBank.Contains("")) OrElse item.OtherSupplierAccount.Contains("")) OrElse item.OtherSupplierBranch.Contains("")) OrElse item.ShortDesc.Contains("")) OrElse item.Comment.Contains("")))}

Comment: It looks it's because of the OrderBy clause

Comment: Hi @Morgs, what `OrderBy` clause? Before posting it, I've tested the above (of course on entity with less string properties) as `Where` clause and it worked. Btw, when `someStringColumn` is null or empty, we should probably skip the whole `Or` expression.

Comment: it's this line here: OrderBy( String.Format( "{0} {1}", pm.SortBy, pm.Sort ) ). I've referenced System.Linq.Dynamic; but it looks like it also wants an expression for the OrderBy() function and not that string I am passing it. If I remove it along with the Skip & Take functions then it works. Do you know how I can create a custom Sort expression based on T? As above the Sort and SortBy as passed as parameters in the PagingModel pm

Comment: Ah, that `OrderBy`. I was thinking the question is just for `Where` :) It should be possible. What do `pm.SortBy` and `pm.Sort` contain?

Comment: They're both strings, e.g. SortBy will be "Id" and Sort will be "ASC"
Yes I know the question is for the where clause but I thought you could assist with the OrderBy as well. Lol :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found the initial problem to my OrderBy. Fixed it like:
`pm.SortBy = ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( pm.SortBy ) ) ? "Id" : pm.SortBy;`
`pm.Sort = ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( pm.Sort ) ) ? "ASC" : pm.Sort;`

So both Sort and SortBy where actually empty...

Comment: Cool. Dynamic LINQ in action :)